# Implementation apriori in SQL

Tags: sql, data-mining

I want to implement this pseudo code in SQL.
This is my code:

```
k = 1    
C1 = generate counts from R1    
repeat    
k = k + 1    
INSERT INTO R'k    

SELECT p.Id, p.Item1, …, p.Itemk-1, q.Item    
FROM Rk-1 AS p, TransactionTable as q    
WHERE q.Id = p.Id AND    
q.Item > p.Itemk-1    
INSERT INTO Ck 

SELECT p.Item1, …, p.Itemk, COUNT(*)    
FROM R'k AS p    
GROUP BY p.Item1, …, p.Itemk    
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
INSERT INTO Rk

SELECT p.Id, p.Item1, …, p.Itemk    
FROM R!k AS p, Ck AS q    
WHERE p.item1 = q.item1 AND

.
.
p.itemk = q.itemk    
until Rk = {}`
```

How can I code this so that it changes columns using k as a variable?

Comment: Your question shows poor work, and doesn't deserve a better "answer". However, it's an interesting question that appears in search results. Here is a [paper](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEQQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thinkmind.org%2Fdownload.php%3Farticleid%3Diccgi_2011_1_30_10215&ei=JHCOU-C8IuLgsASSrYLADQ&usg=AFQjCNHsThh5_25nVCnmudDAvyTAy7UDPQ&sig2=My6_iwCMpDBYWQ2Rf6EDyw&bvm=bv.68235269,d.cWc) that deals with this. It's posible to do it, you just need to improve your SQL skills and reword your question.

Answer (score 1):

For APRIORI to be reasonably fast, you need efficient data structures. I'm not convinced storing the data in SQL again will do the trick. But of course it depends a lot on your actual data set. Depending on your data set, APRIORI, FPGrowth or Eclat may each be the better choice sometimes.

Either way, using a table layout like `Item1, Item2, Item3, ...` pretty much is no-go in SQL table design. You may end up on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)...

Consider keeping your itemsets in main memory, and only scanning the database using an efficient iterator.